# Reuse/reconnect receiver endpoint to new sender endpoint

Tags: node.js, webrtc, kurento, endpoints

I'm using node-js API to use kurento. So, I connect sender's webrtcendpoint to receiver endpoint using code -

```
senderWebRtcEndPoint.connect(receiverWebRtcEndPoint, function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    return console.log("Error in connecting endpoints :: "+error);
                }
                io.log.info("EndPointConnected");
            });
```

Using this code media start streaming to receiver. But, if sender get disconnect -

1. How to disconnect receiver endpoint to sender's endpoint?
2. How to destroy sender endpoint?
3. How to release that sender endpoint from mediapipeline?
4. When new sender endpoint is created how to reuse the receiver's endpoint to connect newly created  sender's endpoint?

It would be more helpful if I could get an example(using JS-API) highlighting these -

- disconnect endpoints from each other
- destroying endpoints
- destroying a pipeline
- reconnect old endpoint to new endpoint
- any event of endpoint notifying endpoint get connected and disconnected to other endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to disconnect receiver endpoint to sender's endpoint?

If you are going to release the sender endpoint, there's no need to do this. In any case, there is a [disconnect method](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_static/langdoc/jsdoc/kurento-client-js/module-core_abstracts.MediaElement.html)

```
receiverWebRtcEndPoint.disconnect(senderWebRtcEndPoint)
```

> How to destroy sender endpoint?
>   How to release that sender endpoint from mediapipeline?

These are basically the same

```
senderWebRtcEndPoint.release()
```

Don't forget to invoke `dispose` on the `WebRtcPeer` object from the client, if you are using the Kurento Utils library. If you are using the `RTCPeerConnection` directly, do also [close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/close) that.

> When new sender endpoint is created how to reuse the receiver's endpoint to connect newly created sender's endpoint?

```
senderWebRtcEndPoint.connect(ReceivererWebRtcEndPoint)
```